# Angular 8+ Observable - Pattern to update underlying value?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, observable

I have a question about using Observables in Angular 8/9. My template uses the async pipe on an observable object, which is great for *displaying* data. But what if I want to *update* it? I'm looking for a good-practice pattern here.

One of my work applications has a service that communicates with an HTTP server to get an Observable. It turns that observable into a BehaviorSubject, and publishes its own observable of the BehaviorSubject. The component injects the service, gets a local copy of the observable, and the template reads its value with the async pipe. The template has an event handler that allows an edit; the component's function calls a "mutate" method on the service, which updates the subject's value, and calls .next() on it.

This seems like a lot of extra work, and I was wondering if there was perhaps a better pattern to follow. When I asked about this pattern at work, I was told that angular handles updating from observables better than plain old objects.

Thanks!

Shortened code examples:

Model:

```
public class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Service:

```
public class PersonService {
    private personSubj: BehaviorSubject<Person>(null);
    public person$: Observable<Person> = this.personSubj.asObservable();

    public mutateFirstName(newName: string): void {
        this.personSubj.value.firstName = newName;
        this.personSubj.next(this.personSubj.value)
    }

    private getFromHttp(): void {
        this.http.getPerson().subscribe(p => this.personSubj.next(p));
    }
}
```

Component:

```
public class PersonComponent {
    // personService is injected in constructor
    this.person$ = this.personService.person$;
}
```

Template:

```
 <div *ngIf="(person$ | async) as person">
    <input value="person.firstName" (click)="mutateFirstName('Sam')" />
 </div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to do the following: `mutateFirstName(firstName: string) void { this.personSource$.next({ ...this.personSource$.getValue(), firstName }); }`

Comment: @developer033 - not sure I get the syntax, but I will check it out. But you say that having a mutate method is the way to go?

Comment: now looking at your question more calmly.. is it your real template? if so, you need to wrap `value` with `[]` to get the value dynamically. Also, why do you use click event on input? What do you want to do with the new name?